# Why is an exception being raised when I mark a RoutedEventArgs event as Handled?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I am trying to mark an event as handled but an exception gets thrown when I try doing so.

I have the following function that gets called on the [`LostFocus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus.aspx) event of a `TextBox`:

```
private void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   // ...
   // do something
   // ...

   e.Handled = true;
}
```

However, the following exception gets raised as soon as `e.Handled = true` is executed:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in PresentationCore.dll
>
> Additional information: Every RoutedEventArgs must have a non-null
>   RoutedEvent associated with it.

I have tried moving the `e.Handled` line before the other code in the function but that doesn't help.

Why is the exception being raised and what are some possible workarounds?

Comment: Have you checked to see what properties `e` has?

Comment: @Bob.: Yes. It does have the `Handled` property that allows me get or set the value.

Comment: Sounds like `e` is null at runtime.  Not sure why, but can you add a break point and check?

Comment: @RickB: You're right. I was calling the function as `TextBox_LostFocus(sender, new RoutedEventArgs())` from somewhere else in the code and hence it didn't work. I've removed the function call and it works now. You should add that as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. `TextBox_LostFocus` was being called from elsewhere in the application with the event parameter being `null`.

Hence, for some function calls to `TextBox_LostFocus`, `e.Handled` didn't work (since `e` was null) but worked in some other scenarios (when it was actually called by the framework).